# Android APK file scanned with virus tool showing Trojan-Spy.AndroidOS.Agent

Tags: android, apk, virus, trojan, kaspersky

I have developed one Android App and published on the Google play store. but when a user runs an antivirus app, my app is showing **Trojan-Spy.AndroidOS.Agent**. becuase of this user has delated App.
Is there any way so that I can assure that my APK file is virus-free. I am new for Android.I used the virus tool (https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload) to identify it. only Kaspersky found this. All other engines did not detect any virus.

How I can find what is wrong with APK

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I contacted Kaspersky Technical lab and shared the infected file. after 3 working days, I got a mail that it was a false detection. So my problem got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It’s related to your `permissions` that u got in app manifest.

But maybe another issue like:

> 1.foreground service with open mic or camera
>
> 2.background service with a high usage
>
> 3.http url in your api calling

and so on

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.. I narrow down it by unzipping the apk file and tried scanning with each file/folder. I got one file that is .dex file which is having virus. .dex files created automatically by Android, by translating the compiled applications written in the Java programming language. dex file is a file that is executed on the Dalvik VM.So does it mean that Kaspersky scanning code and finding any suspicious like tracking location etc..